# Cannot upgrade Ubuntu 19.10 to the latest LTS

Tags: upgrade, 19.10

I need to update Ubuntu 19.10 to the latest LTS version. When I run `sudo apt update` it gives following output.

```
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Err:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I know that this version is not supported anymore. But I can't do a fresh install, because I have important data on this machine.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 or the 2019-October release is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus the archive/software repositories have been moved to old-releases.  Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades but note it's no longer supported on this site due to EOL status (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Key is the EOLUpgrades link in my first comment, ie. you're too far outside the window of support & the move from archive to old-releases has already occurred; thus you need to manually adjust for this.  You can then re-try the `do-release-upgrade`, however if I recall correctly, upgrades from EOL 19.10 were not catered for (*but I maybe wrong*).  You can *upgrade via re-install* though it's easiest on desktop installs (not servers).